# Efficient way for maximum medians from triangle polygons

Tags: python, math, geometry

**Objective**

I have a soup of triangle polygons. I want to retrieve the largest median as vector for each triangle.

**State of work**

Starting point:

- Array of points (n,3) , e.g. [x,y,z]
- Array of triangle point indices (n, 3) referencing the array of points above, e.g. [[0,1,2],[2,3,4]...]

I combine both two one single matrix containing the real 3D point coordinates. Then I calculate the median vectors and their lengths.

/Edit : I updated the code to my current version of it

```
def calcMedians(polygon):
    # C -> AB = C-(A + 0.5(B-A))
    # B -> AC = B - (A + 0.5(C-A))
    # A -> BC = A - (B
    dim = np.shape(polygon)

    medians = np.zeros((dim[0],3,2,dim[1]))

    medians[:,0,0] = polygon[:,2]
    medians[:,0,1] = polygon[:,0] + 0.5*(polygon[:,1]-polygon[:,0]) 
    medians[:,1,0] = polygon[:,1]
    medians[:,1,1] = polygon[:,0] + 0.5*(polygon[:,2]-polygon[:,0])
    medians[:,2,0] = polygon[:,0]
    medians[:,2,1] = polygon[:,1] + 0.5*(polygon[:,2]-polygon[:,1])

    m1 = np.linalg.norm(medians[:,0,0]-medians[:,0,1],axis=1)
    m2 = np.linalg.norm(medians[:,1,0]-medians[:,1,1],axis=1)
    m3 = np.linalg.norm(medians[:,2,0]-medians[:,2,1],axis=1)

    medianlengths = np.vstack((m1,m2,m3)).T
    maxlengths = np.argmax(medianlengths,axis=1)

    final = np.zeros((dim[0],2,dim[1]))
    dim = np.shape(medians)
    for i in range(0,dim[0]):
        idx = maxlengths[i]
        final[i] = medians[i,idx]



    return final
```

Now I am creating the final median vector matrix using an empty matrix first. The lengths are calculated using np.linalg.norm and collected in a matrix. For this matrix, the argmax method is used to identify to target median vector.

**Problem**

*Old:However, I am somehow confused by the dimensionality and currently not able to get this to work or to understand if the result is correct.*
Does somebody know how to do this correctly and/or if this approach is efficient?

My target would be a construct of the 3 medians in form of [n_polygons, 3( due to 3 medians), 2 (start and end point), 3 (xyz)]

Using the max lengths information, i would like to reduce it to [n_polygons, 2 (start and end point), 3 (xyz)]

Using this improvised for loop in the function, I can create the output. But there has to be a more "clean" matrix method to it. Using medians[:,maxlengths,:,:] leads to a shape of [4,n_polygons,2,3] instead of [n_polygons,2,3] and I do not understand why.

Example image for medians of two triangles:

[image: Example image for medians of two triangles]

Unfortunately, I don't have a large exemplary data set but I guess that this can be generated quite quickly. The example data set from the picture shown above is:

```
polygons = np.array([[0,1,2],[0,3,2]])
points = np.array([[0,0],
          [1,0],
          [1,1],
          [0,1]])
polygons3d = points[polygons[:,:]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The longest median is for the shortest triangle side. [Look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_(geometry)#Formulas_involving_the_medians'_lengths) and rewrite median length formula as

```
M[i] = Sqrt(2(a^2+b^2+c^2)-3*side[i]^2) / 2
```

So you can simplify calculations a bit using only side lengths (perhaps you already have them)

Concerning 3D coordinates - just use projection on any coordinate plane not perpendicular to your point plane - ignore one dimension (choose dimension with the lowest value range)

Comment: Thank you @MBo for your answer. I know about the  Apollonius' theorem but I am not sure if this approach is improving my approach. I do not have the triangle side lengths, nor do I need them later. What I do need later is the vector of the median. So why dont calculate the median and then its length instead of calculcating the triangle sides, the maximum median and then the median vector? My main problem currently is how to combine the median vector information and the maximum lengths information to a [n_polygon, 2] vector where 2 represents start and end point of the medians